# Why do I return a series of a chars for a pointer return type?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying my best to return a pointer with a specific value. Though, I am not understanding why I am getting more chars than usual. I asked a few people and I was told that I am getting a substring?

Problem: I type in the word hotdog.
I expect to return a pointer at the index[2]. Though instead, I get the chars dog. Why is that? How would I get just index[2]? I am thinking about dereferencing it, but I am having problems in getting the return type to work.

I cannot change the return type or parameters for my function.

```
#include <iostream>

char * GetValueAtIndex(char * const c, int index);
void ReadString(char * c, int length);

int main()

{
    const int size = 10;
    char ma[size];
    char * pointer = ma;

    ReadString(ma, 20);
    std::cout << GetValueAtIndex(pointer, 3) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}

void ReadString(char * c, int length)
{
    std::cin.getline(c, length);
}


char * GetValueAtIndex(char * const c, int index)
{

    return c + index;

}
```

Comment: Why do you expect index[2]? GetValueAtIndex uses an offset of 3, which would be index[3], and the fourth letter of "hotdog" is the 'd', so I would expect the output to be 'dog'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I return a series of a chars for a pointer return type?

You return a pointer to a character, exactly as you state what you're trying to do.

> I expect to return a pointer at the index[2]

That pointer was returned, as you expected.

> Though instead, I get the chars dog.

That is because you insert the pointer into a stream. The stream insertion operator for `char*` requires that the input is a pointer to a null terminated string and the behaviour is to print that entire string. Your pointer points to an array of chars starting from the character `'d'`.

> I am thinking about dereferencing it

If you dereference the pointer, you will get the character that is pointed to (`'d'`):

```
std::cout << *GetValueAtIndex(pointer, 3) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify your function to return a value not a pointer:

```
char GetValueAtIndex(char * const c, int index){
    return *(c + index);
}
```

or simply dereference a pointer returned by a function:

```
std::cout << *GetValueAtIndex(pointer, 3);
```

When you have a `char*` pointer like:

```
char* p = "Hotdog";
```

and send that `p` to `std::cout` it will be treated as a pointer to (a first character of a) C style string and printed as such. C style strings end with `\0`. So it will print out whatever the character the `p` points to followed by all the remaining characters until it reaches the end of the string that is `\0`.
If you increment a pointer it then points at the next character etc:

```
char* p = "Hotdog";
p++;
std::cout << p;
p+=3;
std::cout << p;
```

If you just need to print a single character the `p` points at then send a dereferenced pointer to `std::cout`:

```
char* p = "Hotdog";
std::cout << *p;
```

Comment: I edit the question, I cannot change the return type or parameters for the function.

Comment: @don1123 That makes no sense

Comment: @don1123 If you return a pointer to the character at that index, when printing it like you did in the code you provided will only stop when the `\0` character is encountered and that is only at the end of the string, that is why the ouput for your example would be `dog` and not only `d`.

Comment: @Justin char * GetValueAtIndex(char * const c, int index) <-- I cannot change it and it has to return. That is how it is.

Comment: @Ron Thank you for your edit. I really appreciate it. I made a mistake and forgot a verb in my edit. My fault. I cannot change my return type or parameters for this particular case.